# How to add space with specified string length in php

Tags: php, string

I want to like add space in sting with specified string length.

For example : **Hello** is my string & i set string length 30 so next string should be start after length 30 so it should be like `Hello         Next string`.

I would like to add space..

I have used following code but it's not adding space it's take whole character but not added space.

```
<?php
$fistString ="Hello World";
$secondString ="Good";
echo str_pad($fistString, 45, '  ', STR_PAD_RIGHT).$secondString;
?>
```

Comment: It does add spaces as expected. Keep in mind that a browser will not display all those spaces in HTML, unless surrounded by `<pre>` tag.

Comment: Hm, seems to work: https://3v4l.org/M4X3K

Comment: Okay ,So is it possible to start next string after ending first sting length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did with my self with following way..

```
<?php
echo str_pad($string, 30, " &nbsp", STR_PAD_RIGHT).$secondString;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

as per my knowledge the answer is :-

```
<?php
$fistString ="Hello World";
$secondString ="Good";
$str=$fistString;
for ($i=0; $i < 30; $i++) { 
    $str.='&nbsp;';
}
$str.=$secondString;
echo $str;
?>
```

Comment: @Pavrej, Have checked to set 30 length in your example 2. It's given wrong output appear &nbsp in output.

Answer (score 0):

it will be done by using this

```
$string_1 = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
$string_2= " -space-or-anything- ";
$newtext = wordwrap($string_1, 20, " $string_2  <br>");
```

// it will add second string after every 20th character and also break the line

```
echo $newtext;
```

// result will be like

```
The quick brown fox -space-or-anything- 
jumped over the lazy -space-or-anything- 
dog.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add space with specified string length in php**

```
$temp ="optionA"
chunk_split($temp ,6,' ')
```

> output : option A